# Docker volume has permissions of Docker host user, not container user

Tags: linux, permissions, mount, fedora, docker

I just moved my work data from a partition with Ubuntu to a partition with Fedora (more space).

I'm running a container where the container-user is `root` and the Docker-host-user is me (`id=1000, gid=1000`). For example:

```
$ docker run -dit --rm --name tst-mnt -v ${HOME}/Documents:/Documents ubuntu
```

On Ubuntu, the permissions for `test-mnt:/Documents` is `root:root` and the container-user `root` has access to `test-mnt:/Documents`.

But on Fedora, the permissions for `test-mnt/Documents` is `1000:1000` and the container-user `root` does not have access to `test-mnt:/Documents`.

**Is there a preference I can change or group that I can join to make the behavior like Ubuntu?**

In reality, I'm mounting Git repos in these containers. I want my user, not the `root` user to own them for a bunch of reasons. Thanks.

**Notes on installation and groups:**

When I installed Docker, I ran as I would Ubuntu a command that disables the `sudo` requirement for Docker:

```
sudo usermod -aG docker 1000
```

My groups are:

```
joes wheel docker
```